# Is it possible to enter Canada again after being given removal order?

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, student-visa

I was a student in Canada from 2014-2016, I deserted college program  in 2015 due to severe  depression and couldn't continue the program but I stayed back in Canada till mid 2016 without knowing I wasn't supposed to. I left Canada for three months and upon my return I was forced to leave Canada within three days and given a removal order or something like that due to incompletion of my course.
Is there any chance that I will be allowed back to Canada to complete my program or do another program?

Answer (score 4):

Usually when applying for a visa, one of the questions is "have you every been refused a visa?", and another is "have you ever been deported or asked to leave?"

Answering untruthfully will probably mean that you will never get another visa to any country ever again, and if you answer "yes" you will need to explain the circumstances.

The problem is that visa agencies (because most embassies outsource this stuff these days) are usually looking for any excuse to refuse a visa. If the reasons given are convincing, and they do not think you will enter Canada and disappear, overstaying your visa again, then they might grant you another visa.

Or they might decide to refuse your visa application on the grounds that you already overstayed a visa once, and they don't think anything has changed since.

To answer the question title "Is it possible to enter Canada again after being given removal order?", yes it is possible.

If you have a course of study lined up, and you explain your previous actions when applying for the visa, you might be OK.

But be prepared in case they decide that they will not grant you a visa.

Comment: Visa agencies do not make substantive decisions on visa applications.  Only a government officer has authority to do that.

Comment: Not all countries share immigration data. However, Canada does share limited information with the USA UK NZ and AUS.