# Getting a Canadian visa or pr 5 years after kicked out

Tags: canada

I was an international student in Canada from 2014 to 2016. Unfortunately I was not able to complete my studies due to monetary and personal issues. I was told to leave Canada since I didn't complete my course especially since I did not enroll for the semester during the course of my stay. I would like to go back canada again either to continue my studies or to live there permanently. Is it possible for me to get a visa or pr after 5 years since that incident?

Comment: The answer below is correct.  Canada is very strict with their applications for a Visa — and especially so during the time of COVID.  So your past history is quite a strong indicator that you should not apply for 10 years after your removal order.  Though allegedly, after 10 years your chances increase again.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't been banned from Canada, then you may apply again for another visa.
I suspect, however, that your real question is whether a subsequent application would be successful. The answer to that question is unclear.

You left Canada under circumstances that you've not clearly explained. The question's title uses the words "kicked out," while the body of the question text refers to whatever happened as "told to leave." These are not necessarily the same occurrences, and their effect on a future visa application may differ as well. Whatever occurred will not help you in a subsequent application. Without further information, however, it's impossible to say if this will be a minor or major detriment to a future application.

In any event, a successful study application will convince the Canadian authorities that, at the end of the course of study, you'll leave Canada and return to your home country. Canada trusted you previously, and a visa was granted to you. That's a plus.

On the other hand, your prior entry didn't finish with an as-expected post-study voluntary return to your home country. This is by itself not good, but as noted above, could also be determined to be seriously not good. We don't have enough detail to know.

Canadian immigration will also be interested in what's happened to you in the ensuing five years. Have you generated a successful travel history? Can you demonstrate that you will be able to support yourself while studying in Canada? Will you return (without prompting) to your home country?

Finally, remember that this site is populated by civilians who have some interest in and knowledge of inter-country travel and expatriation. We're not professionals dealing with Canadian immigration law. You'll get a more accurate assessment of your situation if you consult with a Canadian solicitor experienced in study visas. Stay away from "immigration advisors" and "consultants" in your home country.

Comment: If the mention in a previous question of a removal order is an indicator, the likely outcome of an application doesn’t seem hopeful https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15320/is-it-possible-to-enter-canada-again-after-being-given-removal-order

Comment: @Traveller Good catch. I agree.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thank you so much for the reply. Ok so let me try to give you a clear picture. I had 3 years student visa and I was enrolled in college for 3 semesters after that I was not able to continue but I stayed back in canada for over a year. When I left Canada to visit my home country and returned, I was not allowed to enter the country. The immigration officer told me I was violating the rules by staying in Canada while not being enrolled for college. Although I was allowed to enter the country on condition that I should leave in three days after my request.

Comment: @Nits A year is a significant overstay. While the Canadian authorities subsequently gave you a three-day entry, your earlier long overstay will generate significant distrust. Not knowing you were out of compliance with your visa conditions will not be accepted as an excuse — it is your responsibility to know and obey the conditions of your entry. I agree with Traveller above: I think it's doubtful that Canada will issue you another visa. If you're serious about returning, I reiterate that you should consult with a Canadian solicitor experienced in study visas.